# Django: Is it possible to have form field with value compressed from content_object model field in a custom ModelForm?

Tags: python, django

My models.py looks like that (part of it):

```
class GalleryItem(models.Model):

    gallery = models.ForeignKey(Gallery)
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = generic.GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return str(self.object_id)
```

content_object can point to any model. I want to compress values of such model into one form field.
My form looks like that:

```
class GalleryAdminForm(ModelForm):

    content_object = TextInput()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """

        """
        super(GalleryAdminForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        model = GalleryItem
```

Is it possible. Where should I hook in?

Comment: Do you want all possible objects that can be FK in the dropdown, or all the types of the object in the dropdown?

Comment: Just few specific models (Image(),Video(),Sound() in my case). I don't want all content_types.

Answer (score 1):

Ok. I figured it out. But I think it's a dirty way of doing this:

```
class GalleryAdminForm(ModelForm):

    content_object = CharField()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        super(GalleryAdminForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        related = self.instance.content_object
        if related:
            self.initial['content_object'] = related.title+related.file.__unicode__()

    class Meta:
        model = GalleryItem
```

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#generic-relations-in-forms-and-admin and https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#using-generic-relations-as-an-inline

According to this your gallery/admin.py it should contain:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.contenttypes import generic
from gallery.models import Gallery, GalleryItem

class GalleryItemInline(generic.GenericTabularInline):
    model = GalleryItem

class GalleryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [
        GalleryItemInline,
    ]

admin.site.register(Gallery, GalleryAdmin)
```

Comment: Actually I've tried that and GalleryItems in generic inline point to Gallery, because of galleryitems fk. So as if it wanted to add Gallery to Gallery. There is only 'gallery' in dropdown.